# Sql server user defined function BEGIN sentence drops out error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

With this user defined function I am receiving error 'Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'. If I drop out BEGIN, then the warning is gone. Why I can not use BEGIN in this case?

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnMyFunc
(
@MyType int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
RETURN SELECT tbl.[UID] FROM 
(
SELECT [UP].[UID], [UP].[ADDITIONAL_IDENTIFIER], MAX(VALID_FROM) [VALID_FROM]
FROM [CM].[USER_PROPS] [UP]
GROUP BY [UP].[UID], [UP].[ADDITIONAL_IDENTIFIER]
HAVING [UP].[ADDITIONAL_IDENTIFIER] = @MyType
) tbl
END
```

Comment: You can only have 1 statement in an inline function -- so no need for begin or end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Inline Table-Valued Function`, this is the MS SQL syntax.

```
CREATE FUNCTION <Inline_Function_Name, sysname, FunctionName> 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    <@param1, sysname, @p1> <Data_Type_For_Param1, , int>, 
    <@param2, sysname, @p2> <Data_Type_For_Param2, , char>
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    SELECT 0
)
GO
```

For `Multi-statement Table-Valued Function`, this is the MS SQL syntax.

```
CREATE FUNCTION <Table_Function_Name, sysname, FunctionName> 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    <@param1, sysname, @p1> <data_type_for_param1, , int>, 
    <@param2, sysname, @p2> <data_type_for_param2, , char>
)
RETURNS 
<@Table_Variable_Name, sysname, @Table_Var> TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    <Column_1, sysname, c1> <Data_Type_For_Column1, , int>, 
    <Column_2, sysname, c2> <Data_Type_For_Column2, , int>
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

In your case, you are using `Inline Table-Valued Function`, so that `Begin` is not allowed.

Comment: What are sysname, @Table_Var in table definition ? So far, I was using only name for the table.

Comment: It is suprising that this is the accepted answer considering that it contains just copied-out text from the official docs and explains nothing. All this says is "begin is not allowed" which was already known to the OP.

Comment: @FrenkyB those are optional. Refer here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: More about UDF, refer here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Answer (score 2):

An inline table-valued function can only have one statement. The `BEGIN...END` syntax is simply not defined here. There is never a need for it since you can't use more than one statement anyway.

The reason for this restriction is that SQL Server needs to be able to inline the function body into its calling query. This is possible in an efficient and simple way if there is only one `SELECT` statement and nothing else.

Comment: `The reason for this restriction is that SQL Server needs to be able to inline the function body *into its calling query*.` That's interesting. Do you happen to have a reference about this?

Comment: That means that I can also not use DECLARE and other statements in inline functions ? Just one return select statement and that's it ?

Comment: @FrenkyB you can go with multi line table valued function.

Comment: @ConradFrix when you consider that *inline* TVPs have this restriction and they are always being inlined into calling queries I think this is pretty obvious. Do you have doubts? SQL Server does the same thing that it does with views. Views have similar restrictions.

Comment: @FrenkyB yes, the point of an *inline* TVP is that it's supposed to be inlined for reasons of performance. An inline TVP is a vew that can take arguments, nothing more.